# how to skip_validations after a create callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have an User model.
Each User have a profile with some validations.

When I create an User I have this callback => after_create :create_profile

How can I do to skip validations for create_profile

Comment: Why do you need to skip validations on the new Profile?

Comment: When an user create an account he just need two field (email, password)... But I need to create too, a profile with some default values. 
I have other profile fields that I want to validate when user update his profile.

Comment: Thanks for the additional context. Skipping validations is usually a bad idea, as it just makes for more uncertainty down the road as models get more complicated. I think in this case it would be preferable to alter the Profile model, so that the troublesome validations only run on update, e.g. `validates :field_1, :presence, on: :update`. That way `field_1` can be empty when the Profile is created, but when its later updated, the validations will be run. More info in the Rails guides: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I think skipping validations is probably a bad idea here (and in general). Modifying the relevant validations on Profile so they only run on `update` would be preferable, if possible.

But if you absolutely need to skip the validations, then you could do this in the `create_profile` method:

```
def create_profile
  profile = initialize_the_profile

  # etc.

  profile.save(validate: false)
end
```